# SVN & CruiseControl error - The node was not found

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

If I drop to the command line and execute the following, I get appropriate output;

```
d:
cd d:\working\directory
svn.exe info
```

However, if I have cruise control execute the same thing;

```
<exec>
  <executable>svn.exe</executable>
  <baseDirectory>D:\working\directory</baseDirectory>
  <buildArgs>info</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

Then I get the following, (build failed) output;

```
svn: warning: W155010: The node 'D:\working\directory' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist
```

Why is the output different via cruise control?

**==EDIT==**

Furthermore, I put the following in Cruise Control, and found that the first task succeeds, but the second fails with the error above.  This is from a fresh checkout;

```
  <tasks>
    <exec>
      <description>base</description>
      <executable>c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <baseDirectory>working</baseDirectory>
      <buildArgs>info</buildArgs>
    </exec>
    <exec>
      <description>portal</description>
      <executable>c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <baseDirectory>working\directory</baseDirectory>
      <buildArgs>info</buildArgs>
    </exec>
  </tasks>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the

```
<executable>
```

to the **full** path.

```
D:\working\directory\svn.exe
```

http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Executable%20Task.html

```
<exec executable="c:\projects\myproject\build.bat" />
```

I know that the documentation (second example) has this:

```
<exec>
  <executable>make</executable>
  <baseDirectory>D:\dev\MyProject</baseDirectory>
  <buildArgs>all</buildArgs>
  <buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  <successExitCodes>0,1,3,5</successExitCodes>
  <environment>
    <variable>
      <name>MyVar1</name>
      <value>Var1Value</value>
    </variable>
    <variable name="MyVar2" value="Var2Value" />
  </environment>
</exec>
```

But I'm speaking from experience. The full path (as in example 1) has served me better.

EDIT.

Why is your baseDirectory a "fragment" ?

portal
      c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe
      working\directory
      info

Why isn't it

```
 <baseDirectory>d:\someRealBaseFolder\working\directory</baseDirectory>
```

or

```
 <baseDirectory>dc:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\</baseDirectory>
```

Comment: didn't work i'm afraid.  I extended the question to include the full path.